# Heroku pg migration error "PG:DataCorrupted: Error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I am getting the following error when trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`. I have tried `heroku pg:reset`, I have tried `heroku restart`. I also tried creating a new app and starting over, but the problem persists. What could be the problem here?

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.7662
Migrating to CreateChannels (20140424224543)
==  CreateChannels: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:channels)
PG::DataCorrupted: ERROR:  could not read block 0 in file "base/57396/12684": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
: CREATE TABLE "channels" ("id" serial primary key, "name" character varying(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DataCorrupted: ERROR:  could not read block 0 in file "base/57396/12684": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
: CREATE TABLE "channels" ("id" serial primary key, "name" character varying(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:190:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:617:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20140424224543_create_channels.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:709:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

[Edit] My migration file for creating the channels table looks like the following (Nothing out of the ordinary)

```
  class CreateChannels < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :channels do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.integer :user_id

        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: looks like a system issue with heroku... ( I'm getting this, too - 45 minutes after you and @yong )

Comment: im experiencing this as well...

Comment: Oh dear. Contact Heroku support urgently. Make sure you do not shut down any followers, and stop any backup rotation you may have so that you do not discard old backups. Get them to take a filesystem level backup of your database. This strongly suggests possible data corruption. What exact PostgreSQL version are you running? When did this first happen?

Comment: Any news from Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, I deleted the database from https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps (this was Navy)
Added a new PG Database (this was blue)

```
From the terminal ran:
heroku config

You should see your db url
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://your-db-url

Ran
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

And everything worked.
I am still not sure why that happened!

Answer (score 1):

I contacted heroku support team last night, I was having the same issue, everything is back to normal now. bellow is their response.

> Unfortunately, it looks like there was an issue with your database
>   last night which caused an outage for a couple hours, however it's
>   since been recovered by one of our on-call database engineers. This
>   issue wasn't caused by you at all, it was a hardware failure on the
>   host server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm now having the same issue. I didn't have any production data so will just set up a new database. Very annoying though

Edit: Has just fixed itself when I ran the migration again

Edit 2: Is still broken. When I tried to run my second migration file I get the error

```
PG::DataCorrupted: ERROR:  could not read block 1 in file "base/117039/12684": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
```

Very annoying

Just tried to file a ticket on Heroku. Filled out the form with loads of information and submitted only to get a message to say that I have not created any support tickets!